# Passing arguments to a javascript file via POST request

Tags: javascript, backend, nightmare

I would like to be able to run a web automation script file using POST requests. Here is one code example where for example I'd like to pass an argument to the file to run .goto() with a user specified URL instead of the one shown:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
  .click('#search_button_homepage')
  .wait('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a')
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a').href;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

Is there any way to pass arguments like this directly into .js files?

Comment: Wrap this in a function that accepts an argument and pass the url in the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call to `nightmare` in a function that accepts the argument:

```js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

function nightmareWrapper(urlArgument) {
    nightmare
        .goto(urlArgument)
        .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
        .click('#search_button_homepage')
        .wait('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a')
        .evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a').href;
        })
        .end()
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });
}

// And call it like so:

var urlArgument = 'https://duckduckgo.com';
nightmareWrapper(urlArgument);
```